# pip says that module has already been installed while python

Tags: centos6, python-3.3, pysvn

Now a bit of background of my current setup:
I have Python3.3 running on Centos 6. I'm currently working on a web application using Flask that runs on Apache 2.2.15 with mode WSGI 4.5.3 and virtualenv 15.0.2.

```
pip --version pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/bin/lib/python3.3/site-packages (python 3.3)
```

I have installed pysvn with pip and when I run `pip show pysvn` says

`Location: /usr/local/bin/lib/python3.3/site-packages`

`755` permissions recursively set to `/usr/local/bin/lib/python3.3/site-packages`. And I passed `--system-site-packages` argument to virtualenv to use the global site packages.

Even when I try to import the package from python interpreter it does not work. So it is not specific to my virtualenv setup but rather a global problem.

I must mention that other packages installed with pip work perfectly fine (i.e. flask).

I've exhausted all other avenues before coming forward to you guys. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated as I ran out of ideas.

L.E.

I did manage to install it in the end. I'm not completly sure yet why and how but I presume is was  compatibility issue.

First of all I have uninstalled svn 1.6+ and installed version 1.8.16 instead which seems to be tested against the latest two versions.

Second, I have uninstalled the troublesome pysvn instance and installed pysvn-1.8.0 workbench "sudo /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/flask/bin/pip install pysvn-1.8.0.tar.gz". In this case I have installed it my local environment. The 1.9.0 version of pysvn did not work.

L.L.E.

False positive, still doesn't work. I'm going to interact with svn via command line from my script.

L.L.L.E.
After installing svn 1.8.16 and svn-devel along with the rest of dependencies described in the readme file I have managed to successfully install it from the source fallowing the instructions.

Thanks for your help Barry.

Comment: Can you please post output of pip list?

Comment: `And I passed --system-site-packages argument to virtualenv to use the global site packages.` Why did you do this? Why not just use virtualenv?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't also have a python 2 interpreter and maybe you are running the code using that one instead?

Comment: I passed --sytem-site-packages just to eliminate this posibility. 

@Bakuriu I have python2.6 which came with the OS by default. As I mentioned in my initial post the script is run by apache with python 3.3 etc. And I already have eliminate this posibility as I ran import pysvn from python directly  python -c "import pysvn" >> ImportError: No module named 'pysvn'

Comment: @user2972134 Did you check that apache is actually running python3.3 and not your python2.6? It wouldn't be the first, and not even the tenth time that I hear somebody installed a package on the interpreter X and used interpreter Y to run the code instead...

Comment: @Bakuriu I've already done that.

[Sun Aug 21 09:59:26 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/4.5.3 Python/3.3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pysvn is not available from PyPI because PyPI has no way to allow me to upload pysvn for each supported SVN version. Let alone deal with the issues of installing on a Linux distro given the choices for pysvn dependencies.
(APR, SVN, OpenSSL etc).

Fedora packages pysvn for the Fedora release.
I'm assuming that means it is on RHEL and therefore packaged by CentOS.
(But I do not have RHEL or CentOS to check this on)

If you find that a package is not available for your CentOs is not hard
to build pysvn on a linux distro. Get the source kit and follow the readme.html should get you going.

Barry (pysvn maintainer)

Comment: thank you very much for your input on this matter. Your comment gave me the confidence that the package is working and the problem is somewhere else.  I was finally manage to install pysvn 1.9.2 and confirm that it is working as expected. In my case particularly I didn't had subversion-devel installed. I know, daft right.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you accept this answer please as you seem happy with it.